# how to write td in side the jsp code . I had written the but result merged

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
        <%@ page import= "myExam.quest" %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%! int index=0; %> 
        <%! int pos=0; %>   

        <% String c,a;
            String[] CA =(String[])session.getAttribute("CA");
            String[] AS =(String[])session.getAttribute("AS");
            List<quest> l=(List<quest>)session.getAttribute("myquestion");
            quest[] question = new quest[l.size()];
            l.toArray(question);
        %>
        <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <th  colspan="2" width="500">Questions</th>
                <th>CorrectAnswer</th>
                <th>Answer sheet</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <% 
                    for(pos=0;pos<question.length;pos++){
                    String ques=question[pos].ques;
                    String opa=question[pos].opa;
                    String opb=question[pos].opb;
                    String opc=question[pos].opc;
                    String opd=question[pos].opd;
                    c=CA[pos];
                    a=AS[pos];
                %>  
                <td>Question <%=pos+1%></td>
                <td width="500"><%= ques %></td>
                <td><%=c  %></td>
                <td><%= a%>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <%} %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I had written every thing is write please ignored the session

the output come is

[output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aJJ0.png)
  only the first line comes in the table format

please suggest some work to perform or how to modify it

Comment: What you are doing is totally wrong. You must avoid the use of scriptlet. It is a bad programming practice.

Comment: Try to write the code which could be atleast understood by you. Format your code neatly to understand whether you have missed any tags or not.

Comment: @dhananjaykumar Did any of the below answer solve your problem?

Comment: @Perry  you had said avoid sciplet , since i am using on jsp then what to use intead of

Comment: Use JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library (JSTL) and Expression Language (EL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very bad practice to write code using scriplets. You should avoid using scriplets. Anywayas, try with below code:

Insert title here

```
    <% String c,a;
        String[] CA =(String[])session.getAttribute("CA");
        String[] AS =(String[])session.getAttribute("AS");
        List<quest> l=(List<quest>)session.getAttribute("myquestion");
        quest[] question = new quest[l.size()];
        l.toArray(question);
    %>
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <th  colspan="2" width="500">Questions</th>
            <th>CorrectAnswer</th>
            <th>Answer sheet</th>
        </tr>
        <% 
            for(pos=0;pos<question.length;pos++){
            String ques=question[pos].ques;
            String opa=question[pos].opa;
            String opb=question[pos].opb;
            String opc=question[pos].opc;
            String opd=question[pos].opd;
            c=CA[pos];
            a=AS[pos];
        %>
            <tr><!-- moved tr inside for loop-->
                <td>Question <%=pos+1%></td>
                <td width="500"><%= ques %></td>
                <td><%=c  %></td>
                <td><%= a%></td><!-- added missing /td-->
            </tr>
        <%} %>
    </table><!-- moved /table outside of for loop-->
</body>
```

Comment: i had added the missing tag , and also move the <tr> inside for loop thanks for it but still the output is same

Comment: You must be making some mistake again @dhananjaykumar. Just replace this code in your `jsp`. This should be working.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala, please tell me how is your solution different from my post?

Comment: I have made efforts to format this code first and answered it. It might not be a different solution but its not a copy of your post. So don't be worried @Arvind :-)

Comment: Thanks@KrishnaKuntala it works . Today i had tried.thanks a lot to both you

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your table html is not well nested within the loop.

```
 <% 
 for(pos=0;pos<question.length;pos++){
 String ques=question[pos].ques;
 String opa=question[pos].opa;
 String opb=question[pos].opb;
 String opc=question[pos].opc;
 String opd=question[pos].opd;
 c=CA[pos];
 a=AS[pos];
%>
   <tr> <!-- moved inside -->
    <td>Question <%=pos+1%></td>
    <td width="500"><%=ques%></td>
    <td><%=c%></td>
    <td><%=a%></td> <!-- added missing closing tag -->
   </tr>
<%} %>
</table><!-- moved outside -->
```

P.S. Also consider using JSTL Core tags for such kind of implementation.

Comment: @dhananjaykumar, I request you to update your post, don't override the existing one, just copy-paste the new code right below the old one under heading **Edited:**. I guess relevant part is `<table></table>`,that would suffice.

Comment: @Arvind The question has been edited by me and accepted by SFO community member which is to be in a readable format. Its the same question that dhananjay kumar asked but in a readable format.